# Select-Object -Property parameter prevents getting object while in loop

Tags: powershell-5.0

Please help me understand why I cannot output the object with `Select-Object` using `-Property` parameter while being in loop.

Here is example:

```bsh
$GPjob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-Process | Select-Object -First 1}

for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 200000 ; $i++) {
    if (($GPjob.State -eq 'Completed') -and ($GPjob.HasMoreData)) {
        "Step 1: $(Get-Date) : `$i=$i"
        Receive-Job $GPjob | Select-Object -Property Name
        "Step 2: $(Get-Date) : `$i=$i"
    }
}
```

Step 1, `Receive-Job` and Step 2 lines should be executed one by one inside one of the `$i` cycles. So I should see all three outputs at once. But actually, I don't see output from `Receive-Job` and Step 2 until entire loop is over.

But if I don't use `-Property` parameter for `Receive-Job`, everything goes as expected: I see all three outputs at once.

Comment: You mean if you don't pipe to select-object?

Comment: Each of the 3 statments inside the `if` should be called just once. There is a delay between the "Step 1" line and the output of `Receive-Job | Select-Object` b/c fetching and filtering that output takes some time, but the output should still be printed during the same iteration (same value of `$i`). What makes you think that the output gets displayed only after the loop finishes?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I set 200 000 inerations for the purpose of seeing when the output comes. Because such a loop takes about 5 seconds to finish. If I make the same code in the infinite DO loop, `Receive-Job` and `Step 2` out will never come.

Comment: @js2010 I mean if I don't use `-Property` parameter for `Select-Object`. I can change the line for everything to be OK:
`Receive-Job $GPjob | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: Hmm... weird. Looks like the pipeline is delaying the rendering of the output, but for what reason I cannot say. What I'd do here is use a `do` or `while` loop to wait until the job is completed, and call `Receive-Job` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This way comes out faster, but I can't explain why.  Maybe it's how Out-Default works.  I got the same results with &{ for () } and foreach-object.  In the ise debugger, if I put a breakpoint on the receive-job line, the output comes out right after I step past the "Step 2" line.

```
Receive-Job $GPjob | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: `-ExpandProperty` works in my case as well as many other parameters I tried.
But it doesn't help me because I actually need several properties to get a table of results:
`-Property Name, WorkingSet64, Handle`

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't find the answer, but I found a workaround.
`Format-Table` fixes this mistery. So the next code works just as expected:

```
$GPjob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-Process | Select-Object -First 1}

for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 200000 ; $i++) {
    if (($GPjob.State -eq 'Completed') -and ($GPjob.HasMoreData)) {
        "Step 1: $(Get-Date) : `$i=$i"
        Receive-Job $GPjob | Select-Object -Property Name | ft
        "Step 2: $(Get-Date) : `$i=$i"
    }
}
```